# Visualization of electromagnetic waves with potentials?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, potential

I wonder if there is out there any visualization of the propagation of electromagnetic waves, not only with the electric and magnetic fields components but an actual visualization of the underlying scalar and magnetic potentials too. Does this even make sense?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand that the potentials in a particular reference frame have some arbitrariness due to gauge transformations? By contrast, the fields in a particular reference frame are well-defined.

Comment: I unfortunately do not understand what what gauge transformations mean...

Comment: You can read about them [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node45.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the radiation gauge V=0 and $\vec E = \partial_t \vec A $  and typically $\vec E = i \omega \vec A $ for a plane wave. So representing a wave by E or A does not make a big difference.

Answer (score -2):

Visualize the EM waves as a form of energy being transmitted as a disturbance in the medium, travelling outward direction. When the stone is dropped in the pond it is the potential and kinetic energy of the medium which was carrying the energy. Light is generated from charge sources (ignore the photon or boson theory) due to the variation in the E and B field at its position, thus this variation gives rise to adjacent variations in the medium. The energy required for its acceleration it carried by E and B field and at any point x, the variation is the one which appears at the source T time back (where v will the speed of EM wave).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not respond to the question.  Please read the original question carefully.